# Get Max value from db and add one

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that contain a sequence like this **B05/FDH/CN/NM/00001, B05/FDH/CN/NM/00002**
I need to get the max value from DB and add **1** to the sequence. the next number would be B05/FDH/CN/NM/00003

how do i do this

**SQL** and im getting max value as *B05/FDH/CN/NM/00002*

```
select MAX(`coverNoteNo`) as cnumber from covernotenonmotor where users_idusers = 8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the result into a string then try this..

```
$string = 'B05/FDH/CN/NM/00002';

$stringpart =  substr($string, 0, -5);                      // "B05/FDH/CN/NM/"
$numberpart = (integer) substr($string, -5);                // "2"
$numberpart = $numberpart+1;                                // "3"
$numberpart = str_pad($numberpart, 5, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);   // "00003"

echo $result = $stringpart.$numberpart;                     // "B05/FDH/CN/NM/00003"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this at **Databse Level**. this may help You in Code Optimization :)

```
select max(coverNoteNo), (SUBSTRING( max(coverNoteNo),0 , 15))+cast(cast((SUBSTRING( max(coverNoteNo),15 ,20)) as int)+1 as varchar) from covernotenonmotor
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are fetching data as array from database you can also try this -

Assume you have fetched a array result set i.e. $arr than you can increment in a loop -

```
$arr = array('B05/FDH/CN/NM/00001', 'B05/FDH/CN/NM/00002');   //values from db

      $b =array();
      foreach($arr as $a)
      {
         $str = substr($a, 0, -5);
         $b[] .= $str.str_pad(substr($a, -5) + 1, 5, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT); 

      }
       print_r($b);  //Array ( [0] = B05/FDH/CN/NM/00002 [1] = B05/FDH/CN/NM/00003 )
```